# How can the Ames test detect a human carcinogen?

Tags: cancer

Using the Ames test, we add a mutagen to auxotrophic salmonella with mutations in the histidine pathway and rat liver extract to simulate metabolism.  How would we know if the carcinogen is a human carcinogen or not?

I'm guessing that if a mutagen showed no growth without the rat liver extract, but then growth with the rat liver extract this would mean that it is a human carcinogen. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

The Ames test aims to find out if a chemical (not yet known to be mutagen) is indeed a mutagen, either directly, or following treatment with liver enzymes (which may metabolise a chemical to mutagenic derivatives during "detoxification"). As you explain, the test involves looking for reversion of various histidine auxotrophic strains of *Salmonella*.

If the chemical is found to mutagenic in the Ames test then there is a good chance that it will be a carcinogen because of the link between mutagenesis and cancer. In practice further unrelated tests are needed to eliminate false positives.

In this review of the method

> Mortelmans & Zeiger (2000) The Ames Salmonella/microsome mutagenicity assay. Mutation Research/Fundamental and Molecular Mechanisms of Mutagenesis. 455: 29-60

the authors state that:

> ...there is a high predictivity of a positive mutagenic response in the Ames test for rodent carcinogenicity...ranging from 90% to 77%...